# Not able to connect to Oracle using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am trying to run a NodeJS(v0.10.36) file which contains connection to Oracle database.

When I try to run the project, I get the below error.

```
M1318657:testOracle yogeshJC$ node app.js

module.js:340
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/oracle_bindings'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yogeshJC/testOracle/node_modules/oracle/lib/oracle.js:2:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

app.js contains simple script to connect to Oracle Database.

I have followed the instructions here to install [oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Oracle Version : 11.2

Following environments have been set :

```
OCI_HOME
OCI_INC_DIR
OCI_VERSION
OCI_LIB_DIR
```

Any leads to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Edit :

sudo npm install oracledb

```
M1318657:testOracle yogeshJC$ sudo npm install oracledb
Password:
npm WARN package.json appdynamics@4.1.10 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json express-namespace@0.1.1 No repository field.
|
> oracledb@1.9.3 install /Users/yogeshJC/testOracle/node_modules/oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsOracle.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsPool.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsConnection.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsResultSet.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsMessages.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/njs/src/njsIntLob.o
../src/njs/src/njsIntLob.cpp:1222:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup();
  ^
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiEnv.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiEnvImpl.o
../src/dpi/src/dpiEnvImpl.cpp:114:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup();
  ^
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiException.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiExceptionImpl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiConnImpl.o
../src/dpi/src/dpiConnImpl.cpp:100:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup();
  ^
../src/dpi/src/dpiConnImpl.cpp:139:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup ();
  ^
2 warnings generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiDateTimeArrayImpl.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiPoolImpl.o
../src/dpi/src/dpiPoolImpl.cpp:145:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup();
  ^
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiStmtImpl.o
../src/dpi/src/dpiStmtImpl.cpp:121:3: warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]
  cleanup ();
  ^
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiUtils.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiLob.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/oracledb/src/dpi/src/dpiCommon.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/oracledb.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/oracledb.node: Finished
oracledb@1.9.3 node_modules/oracledb
└── nan@2.3.4
```

Comment: Please paste the output for this: `npm install oracledb`

Comment: Updated question with output.

Answer (score 0):

You have some conflicts. The error you pasted refers to `node_modules/oracle` which is the older, unsupported module for Oracle DB and is not the `oracledb` module you show being installed.

Recommendations:

- remove the [obsolete](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/blob/master/README.md) `oracle` module
- consistently use the newer, better `oracledb` module.
- check the [install instructions](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instosx): node-oracledb doesn't use `OCI_VERSION` or `OCI_HOME`
- try an [example](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) that uses `oracledb`
- optionally use the [new 12.1 Instant Client for OS X](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/440)
- upgrade Node to a secure patch level.  And preferably use recent release like 4 LTS or 6.